# How can I use Json response from one service to post json data in next service in Nodejs?

Tags: json, node.js, web-services

I am using NodeJs and http module to test my web services(Restful APIs). There are 4 services. The first service gives a json response which I need to create payload for the second service. How to save response in a variable so that I can use it in next request?

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
if (!error) {
    var info = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
    console.log(info);
}
else {
    console.log('Error happened: '+ error);
}
```

}

`//sending request
request(options, callback);`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code examples?

Answer (score 1):

Some abstract code for some abstract question

```
service1.getData()
.then((result) => {
    return service2.getData(result);
})
.then((result) => {
    return service3.getData(result);
})
...
.then((result) => {
    // do something with the last result
})
```